# Python - How to send mail via proxy

Tags: python, proxy, smtp

```
Need help to send mail `(smtp.gmail.com)` through proxy settings. 

Not working even after trying multiple libraries (Including socks)

Latest - Using `xsmtplib`.. but getting following error.

    The HTTP proxy server may not be supported by PySocks (must be a CONNECT tunnel proxy)
```

### Any help will be really appreciated.

Below code for connecting with SMTP server via Proxy

```
"""from xsmtplib import SMTP
server = SMTP(proxy_host,proxy_port,host,port,timeout) 
server.sendmail("aaaa@gmail.com", "bbbb@gmail.com", "Test Msg")
server.quit()"""
```

Comment: post your code of what you are trying to do, cant help till it is clear what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xsmtplib](https://github.com/nickmasster/xsmtplib), an extension of standard smtplib, which supports proxy tunneling.